# Solr phonetic matching vs actual text field

Tags: solr, lucene

I am having an issue with solr result and I thought I'd ask for suggestions here.

I have enabled phonetic matching by including `<filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="RefinedSoundex" inject="true"/>` both at query and index level, also with encoder `DoubleMetaphone` as a variation.

The issue here is that solr is returning only phonetically matched result and disregarding wildcard match or almost exact search phrase match.

Example:

In my index, I have a document with a field called 'name' and value 'Modenine', When I search for `name:mod` , I get a "`Modenine`" which is OK,

But when I search using `name:mode` , note the extra `'e'`, it returns `'Something Foul Mouth'` and this is because, `mouth` phonetically matches `mode`, I don't mind having 'Something Foul Mouth' as a result but I also want to see 'Modenine' since `mode` is the actual search term.

The quickest solution that comes to my head is have a way to add the phonetic code to index during indexing, then use dismax to rank the result by providing score using ^2.0 for example.

I have the following:
Field declarations

```
<field name="phoneticName" type="phonetics" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="phonetics" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

FieldType for phonetics

```
<fieldType name="phonetics" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index"> 
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="RefinedSoundex" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">             
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="RefinedSoundex" inject="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />       
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>               
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But After re-indexing, the phoneticName field only has the exact value of the name field, it doesn't store the phonetic code which I aim to searchby.

I found this [solr-boosting-down-phonetic-variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956088/solr-boosting-down-phonetic-variations) but doesn't have much detail.

Thanks
P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work when I enter `mod` as query, I get about 5 related result including `modenine`. How I managed to do this is by using Ngram filter which is not something I just found out, In fact, I've had Ngram filter added to list of filters in schema.xml from inception but never really worked as anticipated.

The mistake is that I am applying NgramFilter at both `index` and `query` level/phase.
Ngram should only be added at `index` phase, After removing the Ngram filer at query phase, I got required result.

See config below, Notice how I have added: `solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory` to remove possible duplicates from NGramFilterFactory filters.

```
<fieldType name="phonetics" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">         
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="1000"  />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="0" 
        generateWordParts="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateNumberParts="0"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">     
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="0" 
        generateWordParts="1" stemEnglishPossessive="0" generateNumberParts="0"
        catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>        
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>        
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="true"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Cheers

Babajide

Comment: Another way of achieving this without using NgramFilter since analysis affects indexing time, is to in fact do both wildcard and phonetic match at once. e.g (name:mod*^10.0 OR name:mode^2.0) AND other fields if required. You could also add a OR name:mod~^1.0 for nearest phonetic match. This also worked for me quiet well. Remember that name must be of type phonetics in field declaration for name. The '^' is for scoring. Cheers Babajide P

Answer (score 1):

You aren't getting wildcard matches because you aren't performing a wildcard search.  `name:mode*` would match "modenine", though it would not match phonetically, since wildcard/prefix searches are not analyzed, which makes sense, because phonetic algorithms work on the assumption that they are working with a complete word.

If you want to search on both, you should use a query like:  `name:mode name:mode*`.

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon, I thought I read somewhere that repeating field twice is not permissible and can result in bizarre behavior. I have another solution for this which I will post now but I will still like to try name:mode name:mode* to see the outcome. Will report back.

Comment: You may be referring to scoring issues.  Multiple repeats of a field can lead to the term being more heavily weighted than you would like, in which case you can use a `DisjunctionMaxQuery` to deal with that issue.  Whether it's necessary or not depends on your needs, but I don't think a dismax query is called for in this case.